# Android: How to change drawable depending on list item selected

Tags: android, listview, drawable

My problem: A listview is presented to the user displaying a list of animals, and depending on which item chosen, the next activity will present the user with the image of the animal chosen.

My approach so far has been to pass the position of the list item selected:

```
intent.putExtra("position_on_list", position)
```

And get extras in the next activity.

This is where I get confused. How can I display a picture dynamically depending on the animal selected?I have tried a if statement approach;

```
if(position == 0){
   ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.animalImg)
   icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiger)
}
```

But this leads to an error when I run the app.Could someone point me in the right direction on how I might go about doing this correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: "this leads to an error when I run the app"
Hello Jnanathan, can you help us? We cannot guess the error you get! Please use the logcat tool in Eclipse and give us the error!
I am pretty sure you will find the error yourself just by reading this log
Cheers .

Comment: what is the error you get? does it make it to the if statement?

Comment: Hi guys, the logcat does not give an error, I am running it from the hardware, it gives a "stopped unexpectedly" error.Do you think I am on the right path with this approach?

Comment: I believe DDMS will give you the error from the device logs. Or run it in the emulator and give us the error from LogCat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as your error, Without any details about the error it could be anything...

I think the if statement is fine, you might want to do a switch statement with a default: as an alternative.

```
switch (position){
 case 0:
 break;
 default:
 break;
}
```

Another option which I personally like is putting your images in an arrays.xml resource file and creating a TypedArray, it's a little cleaner and more Android friendly.

the arrays.xml file would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
        <string-array name="animals">
        <item>@drawable/tiger</item>
        <item>@drawable/bear</item>
        <item>@drawable/...</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

and your activity would have something like this, and no switches or ifs

```
TypedArray ar = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.animals)));
ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.animalImg)
icon.setImageResource(ar.getResourceId(position, -1));
```

Comment: Hi Sadboy, I have tried both of these approaches and am still thrown an error!The error reading FATAL EXCEPTION: java.lang.runtime exception, caused by java.lang.NullPointerException.Any ideas on what the problem might be, I've been trying to figure it out for the past few hours and nothing..

Comment: Maybe you can debug and see what line it throws the exception on by putting break points and setpping when you create the intent, in the onCreate of the new Activity and then on the line when you set the image resource... What point does it make it to? Or wrap all of them in try catch statements temporarily and write out the exception or break on the catch view the exception.

Comment: Without sounding like a lazy @ss, I'm a novice eclipse user and would not know how to go about such a procedure without time  something I do not have a lot of at the moment!I have narrowed the problem down to a strange occurrence - setting the image resource cannot even be done the "simple" way, by that I mean by the conventional icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiger), very strange, very frustrating.

Comment: SadBoy, I have figured out the problem!The line:  ar = getResources().obtainTypedArray(...) should use a "this" reference, i.e this.getResources()... I won't forget this in a hurry.Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.